# How to get the row's whose id' value is used in other rows as parent id value

Tags: sql

```
Id  parent id
1.  Null
2.  Null 
3.   1
4.   1
5.   1
6.   2
7.   2 
8.   2
9.   2
10.  2
```

I have this table

I want something like this

I have one parameter

```
Min parent id count
```

```
Which means if i set min parent id count 2
I should get row with id 1 and raw with id 2

Cause row with id 1 is used in parent id for 3 times
And row with id 2 is used in parent id for 5 times

If set min parent id count to 4
I should only get row which has id 2 cause id  is used in parent id for 5 times

What i want is to check for every row how many times its id value used in as value in parent id 
For here is 1 is used for 3 times
And id 2 is used for 5 times
```

Comment: Postgresql and myswl are two different products with different implementations of sql. Which one do you use? How does this wuestion relate to python or django?

Comment: Cause i have a model which has no relationship to its self someone has hardcoded that table to keep relationship to it seld without any foreign key to self so i have to use raw query thats why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number of ids in column `parent_id` :

```
SELECT parent_id, count(*) 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP BY parent_id
```

To get rows whose id corresponds to parent_id with number >= 4 :

```
WITH list AS 
(
    SELECT parent_id
      FROM my_table
     GROUP BY parent_id
     HAVING COUNT(*) >= 4
) 
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table AS t
INNER JOIN list AS l ON l.parent_id = t.id
```

Comment: You didn't understand my question. My question is based on count of parent id i want to get that row which has that Id. Like id 1's count is 3 times in parent id column and id 2's count is 5 times in parent id column so based on that if i keep min count to 2 i should get full row which has id 1 and row which has id 2 cause both are used in parent id. For more than min count that i have given. If i give min count to 4 i should only get row which has id 2 cause it is used in parent id for 5 times

Comment: solution is updated; the second query should provide the expected result of "If i give min count to 4 i should only get row which has id 2 cause it is used in parent id for 5 times"